# error while modifying pom.xml file using PowerShell

Tags: arrays, xml, powershell, loops

I want to modify some Text value in `<module>features/com.bw.rest.runtime.feature</module>` to `<module>features/com.bw.rest.runtime.feature.eclipse</module>`. I am unable to locate node value `<module>features/com.bw.rest.runtime.feature.eclipse</module>` using PowerShell. As I want to update all the modules value under modules as .eclipse at the end of the string. Below is the full code section in which I want to modify the Text. Please help.

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.bw.hello.feature</groupId>
<groupId>com.bw.hello.feature</groupId>
<artifactId>model</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
   <modules>
     <module>features/com.bw.rest.runtime.feature</module>
     <module>plugins/com.bw.rest.jaxrs.runtime</module>
     <module>plugins/com.bw.rest.runtime</module>
     <module>plugins/com.bw.rest.runtime.schema</module> 
     <module>plugins/com.bw.rest.swagger.runtime</module>
     <module>plugins/com.bw.swagger.model.client</module>
     </modules>
```

I have tried below code. But I don't want to change one by one i want to update all strings in modules with .eclipse

```
$filePath = "C:\Users\Documents\example\temp1.xml"
$f = "features/com.bw.rest.runtime.feature"
Get-ChildItem $filePath -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
# Read the file and use replace()
(Get-Content $_).Replace("$f","features/com.bw.rest.runtime.feature.eclipse") | Set-Content $_
```

}

Comment: Can you add the code you have already tried to make in order to parse the xml?

Comment: @ThomErnst I have tried the below code to replace feature string which is given under modules section. But want to update all the strings under <Modules ><module> of feature and plugins with .eclipse extension at the end of each string.

$filePath = "C:\Users\Documents\example\temp1.xml"
$f = "com.bw.rest.runtime.feature"

# Get the files from the folder and iterate using Foreach

Get-ChildItem $filePath -Recurse | ForEach-Object {

# Read the file and use replace()
(Get-Content $_).Replace("$f","com.bw.rest.runtime.feature.eclipse") | Set-Content $_
}

Answer (score 0):

Use Xml Linq :

```
using assembly System 
using assembly System.Linq
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$outputFilename = "c:\temp\test1.xml"
$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)

$modules = $xDoc.Descendants("module")
foreach($module in $modules)
{
   $module.SetValue($module.Value + ".eclipse")
}
$xDoc.Save($outputFilename)
```

Comment: I tried above code but its giving me an error 
Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: project. Line 19, 
position 1."
At line:7 char:1
+ $xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : XmlException 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:9 char:1
$modules = $xDoc.Descendants("module")

Comment: The XML is not well formed.  Error says :  "Unexpected end of file has occurred.  A well formed XML file has only one root tag.  You have an array of tags.  When I tested I added to the beginning <Test>  and at the end </Test> so there was only one root element.